# Is this a correct way of using the Web Audio API? (slight sound artifacts)

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I put together a function that plays some tones, however, I can hear from time to time some weird artifacts. I'm new to the  Web Audio API, and  I don't know if I'm doing things correctly. I'd appreciate suggestions.

Here is my code:

```
export class ToneService {
  tone = 310;
  audioContext!: AudioContext;

  playSequenceSound() {
    // console.log(this.tone, 'tone');
    const sequence = [310, 330, 350, 370, 390, 410, 430];

    if (!this.audioContext) {
      this.audioContext = new AudioContext();
    }
    const oscillator = this.audioContext.createOscillator();
    oscillator.type = 'sine';
    const gainNode = this.audioContext.createGain();
    gainNode.gain.value = 0.05;
    oscillator.connect(gainNode);
    gainNode.connect(this.audioContext.destination);
    oscillator.frequency.setValueAtTime(
      this.tone,
      this.audioContext.currentTime
    );
    oscillator.start();
    // Stop the oscillator after a short duration (adjust as needed)
    setTimeout(() => {
      oscillator.stop();
      this.tone === sequence[sequence.length - 1]
        ? (this.tone = sequence[0])
        : (this.tone = sequence[sequence.indexOf(this.tone) + 1]);
    }, 100);
  }

  resetPlaySequenceOrder() {
    this.tone = 310;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
class ToneService {
    constructor(audioContext=null,timeInterval=100/* millisecond */) {
        this.sequence=[310, 900, 350, 500, 390, 410, 4430];
        this.audioContext=audioContext;
        this.tone_position=0;
        this.timeInterval=timeInterval;
        //if create audioContext.oscillator.gainNode in playSequenceSound will have a little delay cause first run mute
        //so create audioContext.oscillator.gainNode in constructor
        if (!this.audioContext) {
            this.audioContext = new AudioContext();
        }
        this.oscillator = this.audioContext.createOscillator();
        this.oscillator.type = 'sine';
        this.gainNode = this.audioContext.createGain();
        this.gainNode.gain.value = 1;
        //add this flag because oscillator.start only can run once
        this.fire=true;
        //add this flag because disconnect only can run after connect
        this.can_press=true;
    }
    destructor(){
        this.oscillator.stop();
    }
    setSeq(sequence = [310, 900, 350, 500, 390, 410, 4430]){
        this.sequence=sequence;
        this.tone_position=0;
    }
    playSequenceSound() {
        var cur_time=this.audioContext.currentTime;
        this.oscillator.frequency.setValueAtTime(
            this.sequence[this.tone_position],
            cur_time
        );
        if(this.fire==true){
            this.oscillator.start(cur_time);
            this.fire=false;
        }
        if(this.can_press==true){
            this.oscillator.connect(this.gainNode);
            this.gainNode.connect(this.audioContext.destination);
            this.can_press=false;
        }
        setTimeout(()=>{
            this.oscillator.disconnect(this.gainNode);
            this.gainNode.disconnect(this.audioContext.destination);
            this.can_press=true;
            this.tone_position+=1;
            this.tone_position%=this.sequence.length;
        },this.timeInterval);
    }
    resetPlaySequenceOrder() {
        this.tone_position = 0;
    }
}
var serv=new ToneService();
function buttonClick(){
  serv.playSequenceSound();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="buttonClick()">Run Sound</button>
```

**1.Create audioContext.oscillator.gainNode in constructor avoid any delay when you playsound**

**2.Oscillator.start only can play once,take care**

**3.Run my code on "Run code snippet" "full page" button will work fine,on current page something wrong happened!!!**